# Change Text Colour in HTML5

Tags: html, css

How do I change the text colour using css?  How do I have three different colours on one line?  I use preformated text a lot, so I'd rather not use the 'p' tag as it generates extra line feeds.  Maybe you could point me in the right direction for what to learn next.  Thanks.

Comment: Try using: `<span style="color: red;">This is red</span><span style="color: blue;">This is blue</span>`

Comment: What do you mean by "three different colours on one line"? If you mean a line which has content of different colors, you can use inline <span>  to style specific content.

Comment: Thanks for that. You have coreectly identified that I need to learn the 'span' tag. The best answer was @Ronald Aaronson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One variant:

```html
Not colored <span class="orange">Orange</span> and <span class="green">Green</span> + <span class="blue">Blue</span>
```

css:

```css
.orange{color: orange}
.green {color: green}
.blue {color: blue}
```

For more docs you can browse `color` property.